# convert xml text in csv python

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing

I have a csv file where 1 of the columns of information is in XML format.  I'd like to be able to parse this information into separate columns and re-save it.  I am trying to do this with python, but I am not having much luck.  I have looked at similar problems on stack exchange, but I am still having trouble knowing what to do.

Thank you for your help in advanced!

K

Comment: Try to extract data from XML by using "BeautifulSoup" (BS4) and rewrite in new column.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the tour and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to [provide your code including, sample input, expected and actual output, error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Piinthesky your comment was unnecessary. From the link you shared: "Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some." User is asking how to parse XML; including code about how they have read csv files probably isn't going to add anything of value, and, even if it did, the question is not necessarily about a specific problem with specific code.

Answer (score 1):

ElementTree is a python XML parser  ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html  )

parse the XML literals in the CSV cells as strings, then iterate through the elements and resave them :

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML

parsed = XML('''
<root>
  <group>
    <child id="a">This is child "a".</child>
    <child id="b">This is child "b".</child>
  </group>                                     // replace this with a variable that contains your XML string literals
  <group>
    <child id="c">This is child "c".</child>
  </group>
</root>
''')

print 'parsed =', parsed

for elem in parsed:
    print elem.tag
    if elem.text is not None and elem.text.strip():
        print '  text: "%s"' % elem.text
    if elem.tail is not None and elem.tail.strip():
        print '  tail: "%s"' % elem.tail
    for name, value in sorted(elem.attrib.items()):
        print '  %-4s = "%s"' % (name, value)
    print
```

source :https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html#parsing-strings

alternatively you can convert the XML cells directly :

http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-xml-to-csv-using-python/